# Windows 7 API for Locking and Unlocking Workstation

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a USB RFID reader and I want to use it for locking and unlocking my Windows workstation (eg. analog for Win+L/ctrl+alt+del+password)

I know how to communicate with the device.

I know how to check if the card number is allowed to lock/unlock workstation.

But I don't know How to tell OS to Lock and Unlock.

Is there any OS API calls that can do that?

Thank you.

Comment: LockWorkStation(), you don't need an RFID reader for that.  Unlocking is not possible, the user has to do that.  All you can do is write a [logon credential provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: There's some information about credential providers here: http://blogs.msmvps.com/alunj/2011/02/21/starting-to-build-your-own-credential-provider/ - unfortunately the official guide seems to be an article in the January 2007 issue of MSDN magazine which all links to seem to have broken. Instead go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee310108.aspx and download the .chm file.

Comment: Incidentally, a dupe question exists but it never got an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222323/custom-credential-provider

Comment: I want to use my rfid card to initiate locking and unlocking process, so I need rfid :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at credential providers.

Comment: @artem.pronchakov, what if someone steals your card? Consider chip+pin logon as an option.

Comment: I know about possible security issues, but in my case it's not relevant.

Comment: What is someone will see what keys are you pressing while unlocking PC with password? The same thing...